# How do I access abstract private data from derived class without friend or 'getter' functions in C++?

Tags: c++, access-modifiers

So, I am caught up in a dilemma right now. How am I suppose to access a pure abstract base class private member variable from a derived class? 
I have heard from a friend that it is possible to access it through the base constructor, but he didn't explain. How is it possible?
There are some inherited classes from base class. Is there any way to gain access to the private variables ?

```
class Base_button
{
  private:
  bool is_vis;
  Rect rButton;

  public:

  // Constructors
  Base_button();
  Base_button( const Point &corner, double height, double width );

  // Destructor
  virtual ~ Base_button();

  // Accessors
  virtual void draw() const = 0;
  bool clicked( const Point &click ) const;
  bool is_visible() const;

  // Mutators
  virtual void show();
  virtual void hide();
  void move( const Point &loc );
};

class Button : public Base_button
{
  private:
  Message mButton;

  public:

  // Constructors
  Button();
  Button( const Point &corner, const string &label );

  // Acessors
  virtual void draw() const;

  // Mutators
  virtual void show();
  virtual void hide();
};
```

I want to be able access Rect and bool in the base class from the subclass

Comment: Could you give a short code example and explain why you want to access the private variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. Private members are only accessible in the class in which they are defined (plus its `friend`s), *by design*.

Every class is solely responsible for its private member variables.  If a subclass needs to access those, they either have to be declared `protected` or, preferably, accessed indirectly through some `public` or `protected` methods provided by the base class.

Most of the times, if you really think you must have access to the base class' privates, this indicates bad design of either the base class or your subclass!

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the code! Why do you want to access `rRect` and `is_vis`?  I guess you can access the latter through `Base_button::is_visible()` and `Base_button::show()`, `Base_button::hide()`.

If all you want to do is pass the geometry information from your subclass constructor to the base class, you could indeed call the base constructor:

```
Button::Button(const Point &corner, const string &label)
    : Base_button(corner, 100, 100)  // Presumably, this initializes rRect
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: There are some inherited classes from base class. Is there any way to gain access to the private variables ?

Comment: No, you are out of luck.  All you could do is cheat by using the preprocessor to replace `private` with `protected` before including the base class header, but again this would fail if someone includes the base header before your subclass header.  Can you explain why you need to access the private variables?  There should be a cleaner way!

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to change the base class member to `protected`?  That is the direct way of making it accessible to subclasses.  I don't know what your friend was referring to, other than that the constructor of your derived class calls the constructor of the base class, and the base class's constructor can see the base class's `private` members.

Comment: sorry, but it is restricted to be a 'private' type. Is there a way to access the private variable without a friend or get function?

Comment: You could `#define private protected` before `#include "BaseClass.h"`. (Just kidding, don't do that!) ;)